# jQuery get next element and all of its children

Tags: jquery

How can I get the next div element and then all of its children?

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
<div class="3">
    <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

so, if `$(this)` currently is class 1, how can i get to only class 2 and all of its children. And I can't reference it by its class name since i won't know what that is.

I'm basically looking to merge these 2 statements into 1.

```
$(this).next('div').animate({height : 'toggle'});
$(this).next('div *').animate({height : 'toggle'});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(this).next('div').children().andSelf().animate({height : 'toggle'});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that worked great. I'm going to have to wrap my mind around how `this` became `$(this).next()` so that it can reference itself in `andSelf()` as the original `this`'s sibling.

Comment: The short answer: jQuery maintains an internal stack of selected objects. Methods like `.next()` and `.children()` push onto the stack; [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end) pops. I would infer that `.andSelf()` looks one level lower in the stack.

Comment: You're welcome. Read the `.end()` docs and it gives a bit more detail.